# Passing parameter to onSuccess callback function

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have the following form:

```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("DoComment", "Publication", new { id = Model.Publication.OID, parentId = Model.OID }, new AjaxOptions
         {
              OnSuccess = "publishCommentSuccess"
         }))
   {
           //some code
   }
```

How can I pass `parentId` into `publishCommentSuccess` function?

```
function publishCommentSuccess (json) {

        if (!json.Result)
            showAuthBox();
        else
            alert(json.Message);

    };
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this parameter is passed to the controller action you could have this controller action return it as part of the JSON response:

```
public ActionResult DoComment(int id, int parentId)
{
    ... 

    return Json(new 
    {
        Message = "foo",
        ParentId = parentId
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

so that you could use it in your success callback:

```
function publishCommentSuccess (json) {
    alert(json.ParentId);

    ...
};
```